# Manually add a comment in JComments

Tags: joomla

Anybody know if there's a function I can call to add a comment quickly to a certain `object_id` in JComments?

I have been looking through the JComments classes, but don't see anything apparent.

It would be great if I don't have to manually do the SQL insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did in the end was populate the jcomments `textarea` with the value of the comment and then called `jcomments.saveComment()` with a timeout to give it time to actually process.

```
$( "#dialog-accept-ed-confirm" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Accept plan": function() {
            // Proceed with click here
            var $comment = $(".dialog_comment.accept").val();
            var $setTimeout = 0;
            if ($comment) {
                $comment = "ACCEPTANCE: "+$comment;
                addComment($comment, '.$plan_id.');
                $setTimeout = 2000;
            }
            if ($setTimeout) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    location = href;
                }, $setTimeout);
            }
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $(this).dialog( "close" );
        }
    }
});

$("#accept_ed_plan").click(function(e) {
    href=this.href;

    $("#dialog-accept-ed-confirm").dialog("open");
        return false;
    });

    function addComment($comment, $plan_id) {
        $("#comments-form-comment").val($comment);
        jcomments.saveComment();
        alert("Comment added to plan");
    }
});
```